# needs to display the parent items and sibling items for unordered list via jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Ive got this navigation menu on our website that has already had some great assistance from the community here on stackoverflow. But i need a little bit more.

Right now, if someone clicks on the shop link located at the top, the child elements being jewelery and bespoke appear.

However if we click on necklaces, which is 3 levels down, we have the entire menu disappear.

Ive tried a multitude of different ways to get the third element down to keep its parent and grandparent to stay on screen, however no luck.

What im thinking is a jquery function that obtains the index of the parent and grandparent if the item clicked is the third or second item down. this way this level of navigation stays visible for the user.

```
<script>
$("#navigation ul li ul").hide();
$(".is-current").parent().parent().parent().siblings().show();
</script>
```

we have is-current identified on a 3rd level item, however we would like to display the parent item and all sub items and their siblings so that the menu appears indented and visible if a user clicks on the 3rd level item. Ive tried the jquery code above via js fiddle... but due to me relative inexperience with jquery.. im struggling to find out how this is possible. Any suggestions greatly appreciated

```
    <div id="navigation">
  <ul id="jsddm" class="dbtree">
    <li  id="SHOP"> <a href="...">SHOP</a>
      <ul>
        <li id="JEWELLERY"> <a href="...">JEWELLERY</a>
          <ul>
            <li id="NECKLACES" class="is-current"><a href="...">NECKLACES</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul>
            <li id="RINGS"><a href="...">RINGS</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul>
            <li id="EARRINGS"><a href="...">EARRINGS</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul>
            <li id="FRIENDSHIP BRACELETS"><a href="...">FRIENDSHIP BRACELETS</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul>
            <li id="CHARM BRACELETS"><a href="...">CHARM BRACELETS</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li id="BESPOKE"><a href="...">BESPOKE</a>
          <ul>
            <li id="MAKE YOUR BESPOKE "><a href="...">MAKE YOUR BESPOKE</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul>
            <li id="CHAINS"><a href="...">CHAINS</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul>
            <li id="LETTERS"><a href="...">LETTERS</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul>
            <li id="CRYSTALS"><a href="...">CRYSTALS</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul>
            <li id="GEMSTONES"><a href="...">GEMSTONES</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul>
            <li id="CHARMS"><a href="...">CHARMS</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul>
            <li id="COLOURED CORD"><a href="...">COLOURED CORD</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li id="KA FINES (coming soon)"><a href="...">KA FINES (coming soon)</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li id="GIFT VOUCHER"><a href="...">GIFT VOUCHER</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li id="MY DETAILS"><a href="...">MY DETAILS</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li id="MY HISTORY"><a href="...">MY HISTORY</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li id="LOGOUT"><a href="...">LOGOUT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li id="BESPOKE"> <a href="...">BESPOKE</a>
      <ul>
        <li id="ABOUT"><a href="...">ABOUT</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li id="LOOKBOOK "><a href="...">LOOKBOOK</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li id="MAKE YOUR BESPOKE"><a href="...">MAKE YOUR BESPOKE</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li id="LOOKBOOK "><a href="...">LOOKBOOK</a>
      <ul>
        <li id="BESPOKE LOOKBOOK"><a href="...">BESPOKE LOOKBOOK</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li id="SOMETHING LIKE PARADISE"><a href="...">SOMETHING LIKE PARADISE</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li id="OUR STORY"><a href="...">OUR STORY</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li id="PRESS"><a href="...">PRESS</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li id="BLOG"><a href="...">BLOG</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?
http://jsfiddle.net/D3fbC/

javascript:

```
$(function(){
    $('#navigation').find('a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('li').find('li').toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: thats really cool, very close to what im after. but imagine this situation. when the page  loads all sub menus are hidden, but if the user has chosen the third level item, it and its parents are visible whilst the others are collapsed. this is why we are putting in the "is-current" class so we can identify it properly.